# Scrapy Item Pipelines and file naming

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to name a pipeline output file with the spider name and a date.
I've written a small piece of code that gets called to date the file.
The issue is with the spider name.
Below are two methods. Both work, but I'd like to understand the nuances.
The first method generates a suggestion from PyCharm that I don't understand especially because it follows the example from [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file).

**First method:**

```
# pipelines.py

# Cannot add spider as input to class Pipeline
class CsvPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        # Call to put file in correct directory
        redefine_dir(spider, file_type='csv')
        # Call to name file correctly
        name = dated_filename(spider, '.csv')
        # PyCharm insists the following two lines should be in __init__; Why?
        # Only seem to be able to have spider as input to open_spider and not the class
        self.file = open(name, 'wb')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

**Second method:**

```
class JsonPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # As I cannot figure out how spider is an input to __init__ I have to create a temporary file
        # This temporary file is renamed later.
        print('Current working directory:', os.getcwd())
        if os.getcwd() == 'C:\\PycharmProjects\\ABC\\abc\\run':
            os.chdir('..')
        elif os.getcwd() == 'C:\\PycharmProjects\\ABC':
            os.chdir('abc')
        print('Current working directory now:', os.getcwd())
        # Temporary file created
        self.file = open('data/raw.json', 'wb')
        self.exporter = JsonItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()
        new_name = dated_filename(spider, '.json')
        print('Current working directory:', os.getcwd())
        if os.getcwd() == 'C:\\PycharmProjects\\ABC\\abc\\run':
            os.chdir('..')
        elif os.getcwd() == 'C:\\PycharmProjects\\ABC':
            os.chdir('abc')
        print('Current working directory now:', os.getcwd())
        # Rename file to dated filename
        rename('data/raw.json', new_name)

    def process_item(self, item):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

1. Is it possible to include spider as input to Pipeline class? If so, how?
2. Is it possible to include spider as input to Pipeline class **init**? If so, how?
3. Why does PyCharm insist I should put the self.file and self.exporter under **init**?
4. Any better ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with the first method, other than the PyCharm warnings? You can silence those by defining those variables with `None` as value in `__init__`.

Comment: I discovered that one or both of these methods cause a problem with closing the spider. Need to dig a little more to understand why. I understand why PyCharm wants these in __init__: to configure the class parameters initially instead of later. If I use `None` the file parameter is not defined as `_io.FileIO` and creates an Exception error because it cannot be written to by the crawler/pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this:
[Share global variables across modules](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules)

So I created a config.py:

```
#config.py
name = None
```

In my spider:

```
#spiderx.py

import abc.config

class SpiderBotX(Spider):
    name = 'spiderx'
    abc.config.name = name
    ...
```

Then revised as follows:

```
#pipelines.py
import abc.config

class JsonPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        # use config.py name variable to store and pass spider name between modules
        prefix = abc.config.name
        redefine_dir(prefix, file_type='csv')
        filename = dated_filename(prefix, '.csv')
        # open defines as _io.FileIO
        self.file = open(filename, 'wb')
        self.exporter = JsonItemExporter(self.file)

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()
```

Where redefine_dir and dated_filename are functions to put serialize and file in correct directory based on spider name.

End result: prefixed & serialized file stored in desired directory with no crawler errors and no need to ignore warnings.